# Making point move to right or left using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine

I want to make a point and the point can move to the right or to the left. To make the point I can handle it , but I can already confused in the movement of the point.

This code for draw point

```
public void DrawPoint(ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveView activeView, System.Int32 x, System.Int32 y)
    {
        if (activeView == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IScreenDisplay screenDisplay = activeView.ScreenDisplay;
        screenDisplay.StartDrawing(screenDisplay.hDC, (System.Int16)ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.esriScreenCache.esriNoScreenCache); 
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ISimpleMarkerSymbol simpleMarkerSymbol = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.SimpleMarkerSymbol();
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ISymbol symbol = simpleMarkerSymbol as ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ISymbol; 
        screenDisplay.SetSymbol(symbol);
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IDisplayTransformation displayTransformation = screenDisplay.DisplayTransformation;
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint point = displayTransformation.ToMapPoint(x, y);
        screenDisplay.DrawPoint(point); 
        screenDisplay.FinishDrawing();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you want to achieve and your code is about drawing a point as a graphic on the screen. You can manipulate geometries, including points, with the [ITransform2D](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#ITransform2D.htm) interface. One of the methods is *Move*.